# Change Verbose default color

Tags: powershell, verbose

The default color of verbose output (e.g. `Write-Verbose` or `-Verbose` switch) in Powershell is yellow. This makes it look like warnings, although it's non-critical.

How can I change the default color of verbose output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible hosing the [$Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#host) automatic variable.

In your [$Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7#the-profile-variable) add:

```
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = 'Cyan'
```

(You can use any valid [ConsoleColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor?view=net-7.0).)